Nodemailer not working with firebase cloud function
Hi so I've been trying to send an email with a cloud function but it's not working, although it doesn't return an error. I've tried to tweak things here and there but it just seems to not send an email. Not sure what to do from here, but this is what I have so far:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

admin.initializeApp();

const SENDER_EMAIL = "my email";
const SENDER_PASSWORD = "password";   

// Function to send a verification code via email

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    type: "SMTP",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'email',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  });




exports.sendVerificationCode = functions.https.onCall((request) => {



  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxxxxx',
    to: 'xxxxx',
    subject: 'Email from Firebase',
    text: 'TEST TEST'
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send('Error sending email');
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.send('Email sent successfully');
    }
  });


});

here is how I call it from my swift app
   func sendVerificationCode(to email: String, uid: String) {
        let functions = Functions.functions()
        
        functions.httpsCallable("sendVerificationCode").call([]) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error sending verification code: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Verification code sent successfully.")
            }
        }


If you want to write a callable function, I suggest reviewing the documentation on that.  Your code is trying to use a variable called res which doesn't exist for callables.  That's only for HTTP type functions, which is a different thing.

Also I suggest looking at your function logs for specific error messages. You probably have messages there that would help you diagnose the problems you've having.
